# Converting int to int? possible update?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I built my project locally and it worked with a code similar to the following:

```
bool success = true;
int y = 0;
int? x = success ? y : null;
```

But our build machine failed with the following error:

> error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined
> because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'

So, I had to update the code to:

```
bool success = true;
int y = 0;
int? x = success ? (int?)y : null;
```

That made the build machine build the project properly. I am assuming that happened due to some kind of update I had locally that the build machine didn't have. Maybe a C# update, but I couldn't find anything. Does anybody know if there was any update related to this recently and do you have a link to a documentation?

System info:

- Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac

  - Version 8.8.3 (build 16)

    - GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    - Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)
    - Package version: 612000107

Comment: This has been a requirement for as long as I can remember. It might help if you could list the MSBuild version on your local machine and on your build machine

Comment: With C# 9 conditional operators are now target typed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: it would be a lot more useful to compare your local VS to the build machine config.

Comment: If you build with .NET 5 SDK, it should be fine. If you build with .NET Core 3.1 SDK, that will fail.

Comment: The error complained about `null` not `y`. Before .NET 5, the compiler can't infer what type that `null` is. You can fix that with `(int?)null`

Comment: I prefer the `int? x = success ? y : new int?();` version over casting `y`. This will work on .NET framework, .NET Core, and .NET 5.0. But, as others have said, if you're using .NET 5.0, you should be able to do `success ? y : null` just fine.

Comment: @juharr That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! That helped a lot =) You are awesome!

Comment: @Marcelo Note that `success ? y : null` will not work with type inference though (e.g., `var x = ...`). That's another reason why I prefer `new int?`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need C# 9.0 (or later) to use such "target-typed" conditionals.

For example, with VS 2019, and a target framework of .NET Core 3.1, the following is generated for your original code:

> error CS8400: Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not
> available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

Changing the target framework to .NET 5.0 (implicitly using the C# 9.0 standard) resolves the issue. (You may need to update your Visual Studio installation to have access to the .NET 5 framework build tools.)

Comment: See also here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#target-typed--and-

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I was reading the following link sent by @Juharr and I understand it better now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: I won't make any changes to our build machine tho, I was asking just for learning.

Answer (score 3):

According to @juharr:

> With C# 9 conditional operators are now target typed
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

The documentation sent by him states the following:

> Beginning with C# 9.0, conditional expressions are target-typed. That
> is, if a target type of a conditional expression is known, the types
> of consequent and alternative must be implicitly convertible to the
> target type, as the following example shows:

```
var rand = new Random();
var condition = rand.NextDouble() > 0.5;

int? x = condition ? 12 : null;

IEnumerable<int> xs = x is null ? new List<int>() { 0, 1 } : new int[] { 2, 3 };
```

That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @juharr